# Is there any IDE or plugin that highlights the selected react component in the browser?

Tags: reactjs, plugins, ide, browser-extension

There are times when it's hard to read which code corresponds to which part of the page in the browser. It would be very helpful if the component or jsx tag that you select in the editor gets highlighted in the browser.

Is there any IDE (vscode, webstorm, etc) or a plugin that does this?
And if not, any suggestions on how to approach the problem?

Comment: There is Chrome extention called `React Developer Tools` which has this functionallity.

Comment: Yes, I know `React Developer Tools` and that it can highlight the selected component. But I can only select the component inside the browser. I want to select the component **inside the IDE editor**, not from the browser. Please correct me if i'm wrong.